# How can I solve NameError from Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody help me to resolve the following error from Ruby on rails.

## Error:

```
NameError in PostsController#index

    undefined local variable or method `sort_column' for #<PostsController:0xeeeaf8>
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

While I am trying to get index page the above error is coming.My code snippets are given below.

## views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<% title "posts" %>

<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get', :id => "posts_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id="posts"><%= render 'posts' %></div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

## controller/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

## views/posts/_posts.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "Name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "Title" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "Content" %></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
<br />
```

## application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
  end
end
```

## model/posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

## Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Have you defined a sort_column method? Also consider only posting the smallest amount if code that reproduces the problem - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No,I haven't defined it .Can you please help me to add this method Frederick.Actually i was following http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax" and getting the above errors.

Comment: I don't know what that methid should be doing, but that railscast is a continuation of http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns - maybe check that one out

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should have the definition of your helper_methods, the NameError is appearing because rails cannot find the definition of the helper_methods you are using.